# Find all values repeating more than $\lfloor n/k \rfloor$ times in $O(n \log k)$ time

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, time-complexity

Given a parameter $k$ and an array (not sorted) of length $n$ return all values which repeat more than $\lfloor n/k \rfloor$ times in $O(n \log k)$ time.

I've managed this in $O(nk)$ time, but can't figure out how to do it in the required performance.

Comment: One approach is known as the Misra-Gries algorithm.

Comment: Just found that now! Thanks that's good!

Comment: @YonatanN Write an answer?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: This question was [cross-posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575024/algorithm-to-find-all-values-repeating-more-than-floorn-k-times-in-on-log-k), where it was closed as a duplicate (which points at the Misra-Gries algo)

Comment: @Jason: For future reference: It's not considered good etiquette to post your question on two different stackexchange sites. Choose one, and give the community a chance to answer. If the question really fits both sites, and the first site you pick does not produce an answer within a couple of days, then flag the question for migration, or delete it and post it on the other site.

Comment: I also recall the same question being asked here.

Comment: Can the algorithm here be implemented in $O(n\log k)$? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/91803/explaination-for-variation-of-boyer-moore-majority-voting-algorithm

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Yes, it can as long as the elements have a total ordering. You keep the $k - 1$ candidates and their corresponding counts in a balanced tree (based on the element) which means that you can tell whether a newly-encountered element is in the candidate list or not in $O(\log k)$. Incrementing and decrementing the counts is amortised $O(1)$ by a classic amortisation argument (each element triggers one increment and at most one decrement). If you use a hash table rather than a tree (which is the usual implementation) then it's stochastic $O(n)$, but worst case is worse.

Comment: @rici Make an answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Misra-Gries summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misra-Gries_summary) is a simple technique which will find, for a given $k$, all elements in a sequence of $n$ elements which occur more than $\lfloor n/k \rfloor$ times, introduced in the 1982 paper [*Finding Repeated Elements*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-6423(82)90012-0) as a generalization of the more well-known [Boyer-Moore majority vote algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm), which is essentially the case where $k = 2$.

The Misra-Gries summary can be computed in $O(n\log k)$ time and $O(k)$ space with a single scan of the sequence. However, it always returns $k-1$ distinct values without any guarantee that any of them satisfy the criterion; it only guarantees that if a value satisfies the criterion, it will appear in the list. Reducing the summary to the required values requires a second scan of the sequence to count the occurrences of each candidate value. This scan can be performed in $O(n \log k)$ time by the simple expedient of putting the $k$ values into an associative array implemented with a balanced binary search tree, such as a red-black tree.

In fact, constructing the BST for the second scan is not really necessary because the $O(n \log k)$ Misra-Gries computation actually produces such a tree. The computation can be performed as follows:

1. Initialise an empty associative array $\mathit{C}$ which maps sequence elements onto non-negative integers. The array will have a fixed capacity of $k$ elements, but may contain empty slots.
2. For each element $a$ from the sequence in turn:

   1. *Precondition*: $C$ contains at most $k-1$ pairs.
   2. If $a\text{ is in }C$, increment its associated value.
   3. Otherwise, add $\langle a, 1\rangle$ to $C$.
   4. If $C$ now has $k$ pairs, decrement all of the associated values and remove all keys whose associated value is $0$. [Note 1]
   5. *Postcondition*: $C$ contains at most $k-1$ pairs.
3. At the end of the scan, $C$ contains at most $k-1$ pairs with distinct keys, which include all elements which appear in the sequence more than $\lfloor n/k \rfloor$ times.

The proof of the postcondition is simple: If step 2 was performed, the size of $C$ was not changed, so it is still at most $k-1$ because of the precondition. Otherwise, step 3 is performed, after which $C$ contains at most $k$ because step 3 adds exactly one pair to $C$. If step 4 is performed, there must be at least one pair whose associated value is $0$ and will be deleted from $C$, because step 4 can only be performed if step 3 was performed and step 3 adds a pair with associated value $1$ to $C$.

The intuitive explanation of why any element repeated more than $\lfloor n/k \rfloor$ times must be in $C$ at the end of the scan is explained by @YuvalFilmus in this [related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/91803/explaination-for-variation-of-boyer-moore-majority-voting-algorithm).

The fact that the scan takes $O(n \log k)$ time can be seen from a simple amortised time analysis of the iteration. Every element from the sequence will be added to $C$ exactly once, either in step 2 or step 3, each of which take $O(\log k)$ since $C$ has at most $k$ pairs. Furthermore, each element (except for the $k-1$ final candidates) will be decremented exactly once in some occurrence of step 4. (Step 4 decrements $k$ values, but each decrement pertains to a different element of the original sequence, so the total number of decrements is $O(n)$. Another way to look at this is to observe that step 4 can be performed no more than $\lfloor n / k\rfloor$ times.)

Each decrement in step 4 consumes $O(1)$ time, but at least one pair must be deleted from $C$, which requires $O(\log k)$ time. Again, we rely on amortised analysis to see that the total number of deletions is $O(n)$.

---

In practice, this algorthm will usually be implemented with a hash table rather than a balanced binary tree. The hash table implementation replaces the guaranteed $O(\log k)$ steps with expected $O(1)$ (but worst case $O(k)$). Since the worst case is extremely unlikely, the hash table algorithm is generally cited as linear-time, although strictly speaking it is linear *expected* time.

---

#### Notes

1. As an optimisation, it's possible (and, I believe, common) to avoid adding and removing $a$ in a single iteration. It is also unnecessary to remove pairs which have been decremented to 0 provided you can find such a pair in $O(1)$ for step 2. This can be done with a bit of bookkeeping. You can also implement "decrease all counts by one" by using a base value (so that the values are the stored value minus the base value) and incrementing it by one to effectively decrement all counts. All that will change the iteration step from amortized $O(1)$ to guaranteed $O(1)$ but the extra bookkeeping is likely to result in a slower total execution time.

Comment: Being a bit pedantic, isn't it true that a sequence of `n` elements can contain exactly `k` elements (rather than only `k-1`) with frequency of at least `⌊n/k⌋`?

Comment: @SergGr: yes, which is why both the question and the answer carefully use the phrase "**more than** $⌊n/k⌋$ times".